# Why is my webpack babel setup emitting ESM requires when I have configured my preset to commonjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

Today I observed babel/babel-loader exhibiting some undesirable behavior. I am bundling some assets for usage on nodejs. Post-compile, a bundle is generated with references to `@babel/runtime/**/esm/**`. Of course, node cannot import such files, and on `node bundle.js` I get:

```
Must use import to load ES Module: /my/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

Right. Makes sense. But babel-loader injected those imports. In fact, the parent folder in @babel/runtime has all of the non-ESM things, which I actually probably *do* want imported! My babel config looks as such:

```
{
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        modules: 'commonjs',
        targets: {
          node: "current",
          esmodules: false,
        },
      },
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ]
}
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to tell babel via `targets.esmodules: false` and `modules: 'commonjs'` to use commonjs. I hoped these entries would tell babel to not expect ESM compatibility! None the less, generated bundles still look like:

```
...
var _toConsumableArray2 = _interopRequireDefault(__webpack_require__(/*! @babel/runtime/helpers/esm/toConsumableArray */ "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/toConsumableArray"));
```

My full webpack config is pretty terse as well:

```
{
    entry: serverFilename,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
      path: path.dirname(serverBuildFilename),
      filename: path.basename(serverBuildFilename)
    },
    target: "node",
    externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
    optimization: {
      moduleIds: 'named',
      minimize: false
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json'],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: babelConfig.presets // see babel config above
            }
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  }
```

I can't tell if I'm missing configuration, if babel isn't respecting my configuration, or `<your ideas here>`!

All tips appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's babel and not typescript?.  eg.  `"compilerOptions": { "module": "commonjs", `

Comment: If you look at the shared snippets, you can clearly see that babel is injecting snippets to babel-runtime. Also, typescript proper isn't involved--babel compiles typescript for me in this case. So I'm confident its not typescript, but somewhere in babel/babel-loader land.

Comment: `typescript proper isn't involved`   It's still typescript, there is no un-propper typescript.  It will still use the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: See #3 https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript#caveats . I suspect tsconfig was not relevant

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure out the solution and this post helps
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11696

Copied my solution from the issue here:

I ended up using `webpack-node-externals` in webpack config to sort of bypass this issue

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

// add these to the webpack config.
    externals: [
          nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^@babel\/runtime/],
          }),
     ],
```

This solution creates duplicated babel/runtime file injections and can also be mitigated by https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#babel-is-injecting-helpers-into-each-file-and-bloating-my-code